# Angled thrusters on the Soyuz 2.1a?

Tags: rockets, attitude, thrust, soyuz-launcher

I saw a satellite launch recently ([launch link](https://youtu.be/E0X0KfEnJAk)) which used the Soyuz 2.1a rocket. Shortly after the launch I observed 4 symmetrical thrusters at an angle to the main thrust line.

Is this for stabilization /attitude control? And is this present in other rockets too but is inconspicuous?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the verniers, gimbaled on one axis (tangentially), used to control pitch, yaw and roll. (the main engine nozzles are not gimbaled).

[image: Soyuz launcher engines]

Comment: All the Soyuz series (and their predecessors back to Sputnik and the R-7 ICBM have used these vernier thrusters for attitude control. Early US rockets like Atlas also had verniers, but modern practice is to gimbal the main engines for attitude control instead.

Comment: "...gimbaled on one axis..." Is it radially, or tangentially, or pitch/yaw?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I believe it's tangential -- the bulges inboard and outboard of the nozzle contain the hinges. Better view here: http://www.spaceflightinsider.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/5928-esa_soyuz_sentinel1b-jeremy_beck.jpg

Comment: And another (observe callout #20): https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/space-race/online/sec500img/531l10il10.jpg

Comment: @RussellBorogove interestingly, when there is fourfold symmetry, both "tangentially" and "pitch/yaw" could be true at the same time. Thanks, those images are really helpful!

Comment: Sure, the verniers individually angle tangentially, and depending on how they’re coordinated that yields pitch, yaw, and roll control.